# Нельзя выбрать привязку позиции Rect Transform

Tags: unity3d

В Unity 2018 сенсорные кнопки управления я мог привязывать к определенной части экрана. Потом, после скачки Unity 5.6.4p2 (Pro) - В новом проекте отсутствует выбор привязки кнопки к определенной части экрана, что сделать? (для оптимизации кнопок на разное соотношение сторон у устройств)
[image: Нет выбора привязки к части жкрана]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что Ваши компоненты `RectTransform` не находят родителя с компонентом `Canvas`. Убедитесь, что объекты, предназначенные для интерфейса расположены как им и полагается - в канве.

Comment: Правильно предположили)